# Joining 3 Tables in DB for SQL with Date Format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am attempting to join 3 tables together in SQL, to no avail. My code is below:

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade 
Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 
2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
"Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
"Trade Details".TERM
"FX SPOT".Mid
JOIN "Trade Details" ON "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID
INNER JOIN "FX SPOT" ON "FX SPOT".MID
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > DATE(substr('20180622', 0, 5) || '-' || 
substr('20180622', 5,2) || '-' ||    substr('20180622', 7, 9)) )
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

If I just try to adjoin two tables, taking out all the things relating to "FX Spot".Mid, I get this

```
SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
"Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
"Trade Details".TERM
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details" 
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > DATE(substr('20180622', 0, 5) || '-' || substr('20180622', 5,2) || '-' ||    substr('20180622', 7, 9)) )
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

which works.

However, as soon as I attempt to add the third column, I get a syntax error near "." I followed how to join 3 tables to a tee, so I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You are not JOINING "FX SPOT".MID to anything. "FX SPOT".MID should be equal to a column value in one of your other 2 tables

Comment: So if there is nothing in that column that is equal to a column value in another table, I can't join it? In that case do I do something different to add it?

Comment: That is correct, you have to have a relationship between tables to `JOIN` them, ie. Primary key to Foreign Key relationship. What is FX SPOT.MID that you feel you need to include it?

Comment: I honestly just need a single value from that table to then import into python, because I need it for some calculations later in python

Comment: How do you even know which value of FX SPOT.MID relates to which row in your table join? Or do you just need one value from FX SPOT??

Comment: just need one value from there

Comment: Then you can just append it to the end of your `SELECT` with a subquery, so instead of this: `"FX SPOT".Mid` in your SELECT, do `(SELECT TOP 1 "FX SPOT".Mid FROM "FX SPOT") AS MID` or however you determine the value you need from "FX SPOT"

Comment: So it would be this instead? `SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
"Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
"Trade Details".TERM
(SELECT TOP 1 "FX SPOT".Mid FROM "FX SPOT") AS MID
FROM "Trade Details 2" 
JOIN "Trade Details"` with the WHERE statement after?

Comment: I added an answer below to help you

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want one value from FX SPOT, just append that value to every row in your SELECT, probably would be much more efficient yet to just set the value from your FX SPOT select to a variable and append the variable to your table join SELECT, Since I just found out that you can't declare a variable like below in SQLLite just do the Subquery inside your Table Join Select statment:

```
--Can't do this in SQLLite
--DECLARE @mId INT = (SELECT TOP 1 "FX SPOT".Mid FROM "FX SPOT");

SELECT "Trade Details 2".Portfolio, 
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID, 
DATE("Trade Details 2".START_DATE) as START_DATE, 
DATE(substr("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 0, 5) || '-' || substr("Trade 
Details 2".MATURITY_DATE, 5,2) || '-' ||    substr("Trade Details 
2".MATURITY_DATE, 7, 9)) as MATURITY_DATE, 
"Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1,
"Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_NPV,
"Trade Details".TERM,
--"FX SPOT".Mid REPLACE THIS WITH THE NEXT LINE
--@mId AS MID
(SELECT TOP 1 "FX SPOT".Mid FROM "FX SPOT") AS MID  --Reverted back to this
JOIN "Trade Details" ON "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID
--INNER JOIN "FX SPOT" ON "FX SPOT".MID DONT NEED THIS Since you have no relationship between this value and other tables
WHERE "Trade Details 2".CONTRACT_ID="Trade Details".FCC_ID and
("Trade Details 2".NOTIONAL1 > "0.0") and
("Trade Details 2".MATURITY_DATE > DATE(substr('20180622', 0, 5) || '-' || 
substr('20180622', 5,2) || '-' ||    substr('20180622', 7, 9)) )
ORDER BY CONTRACT_ID asc
```

Comment: There's no way I can just add the column Mid to my existing table?

Comment: @throway172 I guess in SQLLite you can't just declare a variable like in my example, you may have to switch back to doing the subquery, in place of the variable `@mId AS MID` do the `(SELECT TOP 1 "FX SPOT".Mid FROM "FX SPOT") AS MID`